# i want all columns which is having null values more than 50%

Tags: python

I want all columns which are having null values more than 50%

```
df[(100 * df.isnull()/len(app))]>50
```

error: ValueError: Boolean array expected for the condition, not float64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a good idea to provide some example data and expected output. I think this might be what you're looking for:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 

# Example data
df = pd.DataFrame({"A" : [1, 2, np.nan, 4, 5, np.nan], 
                    "B" : [np.nan, 2, np.nan, 4, np.nan, np.nan], 
                    "C" : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, np.nan], 
                    "D" : [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 4, np.nan, np.nan]})


# This will create a series object
check = df.isnull().sum() / len(df) 

cols = check[check > 0.5].index
```

If you want a list of the column names:

```
list(cols)

Out: ['B', 'D']
```

If you want to view the dataframe column data:

```
df[cols]

Out:
     B    D
0  NaN  NaN
1  2.0  NaN
2  NaN  NaN
3  4.0  4.0
4  NaN  NaN
5  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Thanks this is usefull, now i want to drop all these columns df.drop(col, axis = 1) its not working

Comment: `df.drop(cols, axis=1)` works for me. Maybe check what your error message says or print out the data and type for your `col` variable and post here.